# How to change encoding of a text file without opening it?

Tags: php, encoding

How to change encoding of a text file (e.g. utf16 to utf8) without opening it as string? I know it is possible to change encoding of strings using mbstring or iconv extensions.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. To change the encoding, you almost always have to change some bytes. To detect which bytes you have to change and to actually write the new values, you have to open, read and write the file.